# Numerical Solution of Stoke's First Problem

Tags: fluid-dynamics

$f''+2 \eta f-4mf=0$ where $f=1$ at $\eta=0$, $f \to 0$ as $\eta \to \infty$.
The case of $m=0$ arises in the analysis of motion of fluid above a suddenly accelerated flat plate.

Comment: Are you interested in HOW to solve this equation numerically? or  you just wanna look at what the numerically solution looks like.

Comment: yeah, I want to know the details procedure of numerical solution

Comment: Non-dimensionalize around $\eta$ and let $\infty$ be approximately 5.

Comment: How can I non-dimensionalize the equation around η ? I want to solve it by shooting method ? Is it at all possible preferably using MATLAB?

Comment: Sure, you can do shooting, and you can implement shooting in MATLAB. I assume you know how to do this. The boundary layer flow profile above a flat plate starts at zero at the boundary, and as you go upwards, it pretty rapidly approaches the steady-state flow velocity. Mathematically, we treat this as the limit to infinity. However, if you non-dimensionalize your units (make $\eta$ be on the scale of unity), then you don't need to go out to infinity. It's sufficient to set $f(\eta=5) = f(\eta = \infty)$ as your boundary condition.

Comment: You got the point- "Implementation of shooting method in MATLAB" Can you help me with that ?

Comment: I can easily convert the above BVP into an IVP with the following set of differential equations.
f'=g (let)
z'=f"= 4mf-2ηf
Here, for the solution we need two conditions.One is already there i.e., f=1 at η=0.Now I need to guess another condition for f '(η=0). How can i find my initial guess and how to confirm the boundary condition f(η=∞/5)=0 is satisfied by that wild guess ?

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of your differential equation is 
$$ f(\eta) = a \text{Ai}(2^{1/3}(2m-\eta)) + b \text{Bi}(2^{1/3}(2m-\eta))$$
where Ai and Bi are Airy functions, and $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants. Now both $\text{Ai}(t)$ and $\text{Bi}(t)$ go to $0$ as $t \to -\infty$: according to Wolfram Alpha, $$\eqalign{\text{Ai}(-t) &= \frac{t^{-1/4}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin(2 t^{3/2}/3+\pi/4) + O(t^{-7/4})\cr
\text{Bi}(-t) &= \frac{t^{-1/4}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cos(2 t^{3/2}/3+\pi/4) + O(t^{-7/4})}$$  So the boundary condition at $\infty$ does not restrict the solution.  You need another boundary condition to determine a solution.

Comment: It's a second order differential equation and we have two boundary conditions already. Isn't that sufficient enough ?

Comment: Not if all the solutions satisfy one of the boundary conditions.

Comment: I think you have provided the analytical solution but I am interested in numerical solution.Okay, after the completion of numerical solution we can compare the the two results.

Comment: Are you sure you have the sign of the $2\eta f$ term right?  It would work for the equation $f'' - 2 \eta f - 4 m f = 0$
(or equivalently if you wanted $f \to 0$ as $\eta \to -\infty$).

Comment: My prof provided me the above equation & I think it's correct.
Ref- Boundary Layer theory by H Schlichting seventh edition (page -90)